# 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop'

Tags: react-native, babeljs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I am trying to get the tests up and running in my React native app. I am getting the error `'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop'`

I have searched and searched and I am unable to find a solution. Please can someone help me?

This is the `jest` script in my `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "transform": {
      "node_modules/variables/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!variables/.*)"
    ]
  }
```

This is my `babel.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  sourceMaps: true,
  plugins: [
    [
      'module:react-native-dotenv',
      {
        moduleName: '@env',
        path: '.env',
        blacklist: null,
        whitelist: null,
        safe: false,
        allowUndefined: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

And these are my `devDependencies`

```
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.2.2",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.12",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.10",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
```